Can one talk abstractly about the linear independence of points on the symmetric product of copies of a flag variety?
If one considers the (complete) flag variety $F(\mathbb{C}^2)$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$, then this is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$, and thus the symmetric product of $d$ copies of $F(\mathbb{C}^2)$ can thus be identified with $\mathbb{P}(\operatorname{Sym}^d(\mathbb{C}^2))$, which is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^d_\mathbb{C}$. It makes then sense to talk about points on the symmetric product of $d$ copies of $F(\mathbb{C}^2)$ being in general linear position, by considering the images of these points in $\mathbb{P}^d_\mathbb{C}$.
But I would like to generalize this, and talk about points in the symmetric product of $d$ copies of $F(\mathbb{C}^r)$, where $r \geq 2$ is an integer, being in general linear position.
What is an easy way to introduce such a notion please? I personally prefer elementary and explicit ways, but I am also interested in more "high-tech" ways too (the latter may be useful to understand, when it comes to proving things).
